# What version of Objective-C am I using?

Tags: objective-c

How do I tell what version of **Objective-C** I'm using? I'm using a Mac with xCode. The reason I ask is because i have a book "**Objective-C 3.0**" and it says that you can declare an multidimensional array like this.

```
int[,] num = new int[2,2];
```

When I try to do this I get a syntax error. Do I need to import another header other than foundation?

Comment: Why was this changed to Objective-C? The code in the question is definitely **not** Objective-C.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried changing

```
new int[2.2]
```

to

```
new int[2,2]
```

?

Comment: Yeah, I think this is right, it's probably just a typo in the book.

Comment: +1, this is right, if it's from a book then it's a typo. It'd be humourous (or a nightmare) to implement an array that used floating point indices though...

Comment: Continuous tables!  Yay integrals!

Answer (score 0):

I think Walt's answer is right, but here's a good resource for determining which version of C# you're using with your .NET install (thanks to Jon Skeet's "C# In Depth" book!):

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx