# Error when using default value in only get property in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Having the following simple class:

```
class Animal
{
    public string Type => "Animal";
}
```

This does not compiles for the arrow operator saying *; expected*. I was trying to do something like:

```
class Animal
{
    public string Type { get { return "Animal"; } }
}
```

Is it because I am using Visual Studio 2012? Is it possible that in this case make the first version of code compile, without installing another version of VS?

Comment: which c# version you are using ?

Comment: may be useful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764532/what-is-the-assignment-in-c-sharp-in-a-property-signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code sample is using a new C# syntax that allows property getter bodies to be defined as a lambda expression.  This is a [new feature introduced in C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6), which is only available beginning with Visual Studio 2015.

If you look at this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c), you'll see that Visual Studio 2012 only supports up to C# 5.

Comment: "Visual Studio 2015+" since there are no other versions yet and it looks like the + belongs to the version I recommend removing it unless you already have access to Visual Studio 2020 of course.

Comment: @Gill: The [preview edition of Visual Studio 15](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes) is already available, which showcases support for C# 7. Still, I'll remove it.

Comment: okay, but considering the most voted answer in [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532942/which-version-of-c-sharp-am-i-using) if one is building in .net 4.6 shouldn't have available C# 6 features also? Because I changed target framework to .Net 4.6 and I still get the same error. I know you have said that C# 6 is introduced in VS2015 but I was wondering if it can be used in 2012 versions too

Comment: @meJustAndrew: It may be possible. Not sure how well it would work though. Have a look [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013) for possible ways of getting C# 6 to work in an older Visual Studio release.

Comment: Thank you very much, this covers much what I was looking for