# handling no result found

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.5

Following line throw exception if there is `no matching record` found.

```
Guid stuId= context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == student.Name).Id;
```

I understand, i can handle above line

```
var stuId= context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == student.Name);
if (stuId){}else{}
```

But,

Can i make the same line more smarter to handle no sequence found error

```
Guid stuId= context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == student.Name).Id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the [null-propagation/conditional  operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)(new in C#6):

```
Guid? stuId = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == student.Name)?.Id;
```

Now you have a nullable and it's easy to check if there is an id or not:

```
if(stuId.HasValue)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you can't use C#6 as commented:

```
Guid stuId = context.Students
    .Where(x => x.Name == student.Name)
    .Select(x=> x.Id)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(Guid.Empty)
    .First();
```

Now you can check against `Guid.Empty`:

```
if(stuId != Guid.Empty)
{

}
```

If `Guid.Empty` is a valid value you could also use a `Guid?` here:

```
Guid? stuId = context.Students
    .Where(x => x.Name == student.Name)
    .Select(x=> (Guid?) x.Id)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
    .First();
```

Comment: I am using dot net 4.5 means c# 5 so your solution wont work for me.

Comment: @simbada: added an alternative approach if you can't use C#6

Comment: I am checking that. Your 1st alternative solution returns empty GUID which probably not ok for me. All i want it should return null until unless i can't achieve it i am ok with your 1st alternative sol.

Comment: Checking your Alternative sol 2 now.

Comment: I'm getting `NotSupportedException` for `DefaultIfEmpty`. If you replace `DefaultIfEmpty(null).First()` with `FirstOrDefault()` as I described, it works fine.

Comment: @Thanks Tim, your alternative solution 2 looks fine to me.

Comment: Correction/clarification: `DefaultIfEmpty` will not work with Linq2Sql, but most likely works with EF.

Comment: @kiziu: if it doesn't work he can use `AsEnumerable()` between the `Select` and `DefaultIfEmpty(null)`.

Comment: Sure, just seems like more unnecessary lines/fragments of code which can be solved easily by using `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @kiziu: maybe the actual query is bigger and he needs to integrate it into it or he needs to be able to change the returned vaue easier, then this approach comes in handy. But of course, the `!= null` check is easy and short. OP had just asked for a smarter one-statement approach.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be able to use the new Null Conditional Operater like so:

```
Guid? stuId= context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == student.Name)?.Id;
```

You can read about this new syntax in C#6 on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx). Basically in addition the additional question mark, it will check that the statement before isn't null before executing the right hand side. If it is it'll return a null value so you need to make your Guid nullable.

Comment: Variable type should be `Guid?`.

Comment: It must be `Guid?`, instead of simple `Guid`.

Comment: And of course, the assumption is that you use C# 6.

Comment: Correct, assuming C# 6 is available to the user, and then also `Guid?` must be used.

Comment: I am using dot net 4.5 means C# 5. so your solution wont work with me

Comment: @simbada, version of framework is not the same as version of C#.

Comment: Ok, but c# version is linked with dot net version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532942/which-version-of-c-sharp-am-i-using

Comment: @simbada what kiziu said is true - it depends on your IDE. The code will compile down to .NET 4.5 regardless, it's ultimately just syntax sugar being applied by your IDE.

Comment: @simbada - The C# version is that of the written language. The .NET version is the version of the compiled runtime that you'll be executing. You can change the "Target" of a project normally to numerous runtime versions.

Comment: Alright, I am using VS2013. and it does not allow me to put ? after FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == student.Name). Means i dont have c# 6? sorry but getting confuse now.

Comment: @simbada Yeah, that means you don't have it by default. But checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013 and you can be using the latest language features too :D

Comment: AFAIR you won't get the IDE's help with new features of greater version of C#, though it will still compile.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
Guid? stuId = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == student.Name)?.Id;
if ( stuId.HasValue )
{
    // do something if we have a value
}
```

Which is using the null conditional operator, but you still need to check if you actually got a value before trying to use the value

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution working in lower version of C# than 6 (not using null-conditional operator), you can use cast operator like this:

```
var stuId = context.Students.Where(x => x.Name == student.Name).Select(i => (Guid?)i.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will correctly return `null` if no record is found, as `null` is a default value for nullable `struct`s.

Comment: You should make your declaration `Guid?` on the left instead of `var`. It's non-obvious unless you understand all the expressions on the right.

Comment: Indeed, but I always use `var` unless I want a variable to be of more base type, like interface it implements. You can always use the IDE and just hover over the variable to see the type.