# C# 7 ValueTuple compile error

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I'm using VS2017 RC and my application targets net framework 4.6.1.

I have two assemblies referencing System.ValueTuple 4.3

MyProject.Services
MyProject.WebApi

In MyProject.Services I have a class with a method like this

```c#
public async Task<(int fCount, int cCount, int aCount)> GetAllStatsAsync()
{
    // Some code...
    return (fCount, cCount, aCount);
}
```

In MyProject.WebApi I have a controller that use this method like that:

```c#
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetInfoAsync()
{
    // Some code...
    var stats = await _myClass.GetAllStatsAsync();

    var vm = new ViewModel
             {
                 FCount = stats.fCount,
                 CCount = stats.cCount,
                 ACount = stats.aCount
             };

     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, vm);
}
```

Intellisense is working and deconstruct the tuple but when I compile it fails without any Error in Error List window.
In the output windows I have this errors:

> 2>MyController.cs(83,31,83,40): error CS1061: 'ValueTuple' does not contain a definition for 'fCount' and no extension
>   method 'fCount' accepting a first argument of type 'ValueTuple' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?) 2>MyController.cs(84,39,84,49): error CS1061:
>   'ValueTuple' does not contain a definition for 'cCount'
>   and no extension method 'cCount' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ValueTuple' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) 2>MyController.cs(85,35,85,40):
>   error CS1061: 'ValueTuple' does not contain a
>   definition for 'aCount' and no extension method 'aCount' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'ValueTuple' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried adding the **DEMO** and **DEMO_EXPERIMENTAL** build flags but still fails.

Any idea on what's wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

This code works and stats is well deconstructed. I'm probably hitting a bug.

```c#
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetInfoAsync()
{
    // Some code...
    var stats = await _myClass.GetAllStatsAsync();
    var tu = stats.ToTuple();
    var vm = new ViewModel
             {
                 FCount = tu.Item1,
                 CCount = tu.Item2,
                 ACount = tu.Item3
             };

     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, vm);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Issue open on github here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16200

Comment: When you view a debug of "stats" what do you see?

Comment: It doesn't compile

Comment: What happens if you replace `var stats = await ...` with `(fCount, cCount, aCount) stats = await ...` ?

Comment: I have this error ```error CS1003: Syntax error, '=>' expected```

Comment: Is it definitely using the right compiler? Just wondering since it is in theory possible for the intellisense to be using a different compiler to your actual build. Not sure how that would happen but its the main thing that springs to mind as to why they might disagree....

Comment: @Chris How can I check that?

Comment: could deffo be a bug where the Tuple as generic argument is not compiled correctly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532942/which-version-of-c-sharp-am-i-using probably still works. I don't really know for sure though having not played with the latest version. Given how new it is though it might well be a bug as Servé says.

Comment: Does the code compile if you use generic accessors (i.e. Item1, Item2)? My guess would be that this is a bug.

Comment: I thinks it is because you should return some valid value in GetAllStatsSync(), you are doing this `return (fCount, cCount, aCount);`, but fCount, cCount and aCount are not defined. Take a look at my answer, I modified it according to some comments it has received

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If anyone falls in the same trap, to fix this you need to update this package:
Microsoft.Net.Compilers to 2.0 (you need to show pre-release)

Comment: Just a note that as of now (I assume VS2017 RTM) 2.0.1 is released and not prerelease.

Comment: tnx dear @Swell, you save my time

Comment: You are a lifesafer. Code was showing fine in the editor, no errors in the error list, but was showing errors in the output window. A quick search brought up this question, solved the issue right away.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add to the other answers.

Remove System.valuetuple from references. Otherwise, it doesn't work and I do not know why. Basically, value tuple is already in 4.7.2 and so if you use visual studio 2019 you're all set.

If you use visual studio 2019 and I did, that's what worked for me. I don't exactly know why. No need for nugget. No need to reference that directly.

[image]

Target your project to use .net framework 4.7.2 and remove references to valuetuple.

Comment: If it was installed via NuGet, it is better/easy to uninstall via NUGET

Answer (score 0):

I think It is because you've not defined fCount, cCount and aCount. Try this

```c#
public async Task<(int fCount, int cCount, int aCount)> GetAllStatsAsync()
{
    // Some code...
    //fCount, cCount, aCount are not defined here, so you should define them

    var fCount = 0;
    var cCount= 0;
    var aCount = 0;
    return (fCount , cCount, aCount );

    //Other ways:
    //return (fCount : 0, cCount: 0, aCount : 0);
    //return new (int fCount , int cCount, int aCount ) { fCount = 0, cCount = 0, aCount = 0 };
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetInfoAsync()
{
    // Some code...
    var stats = await _myClass.GetAllStatsAsync();

    var vm = new ViewModel
             {
                 FCount = stats.fCount,
                 CCount = stats.cCount,
                 ACount = stats.aCount
             };

     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, vm);
}
```

### Edited with @Swell suggestion

Take a look at [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347)

Comment: The OP wants to work with value tuples but this uses a record class.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the new syntax myself but it doesn't look like the non-generic class was used. The `<>` in `Task<(int fCount, int cCount, int aCount)>` certainly make it look generic and I believe the syntax inside that is the new implicit tuple syntax. I'd only seen examples of it used as direct return parameters but the fact that this compiles suggests that this is the way to use it as a generic parameter.

Comment: I cant find any example using it in the way `Task<(int fCount, int cCount, int aCount)>`. I was almost sure task result is always a TResult, but i'm not familiar with the new sintaxys. I'll trying to find something. Thanks

Comment: Great!!! I've edited my answer following your recommendation, if you have time take a look at it please. I've learned something new. Thanks

Comment: The OP simply included a comment that they omitted the body of `GetAllStatsAsync`.  If they didn't define those variables then the error message would be completely different than what they're getting.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not at compile error, but during runtime.

But I suspect the fix is still valid and could help somebody here too.

After switching my project to .Net framework 4.7.2  I had to manually update the hintpath for System.ValueTuple from net461 to net47

```
<HintPath>..\Solutions\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
```