# ValueTuple: what is wrong with creation of octuple?

Tags: c#-7.0, valuetuple

ValueTuple as a new feature in C# 7.0 is having public method `Create` which helps to create ValueTuples (from `singleton to octuple` or more) on the other hand we can also use `new` to achieve the same results. I noticed these behave differently. I am trying to research is below implementation wrong or this is something as per design:

Method `CreateOctuple()` is working as expected:

```
private static ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<int>> CreateOctuple()
{
     return new ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<int>>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, new ValueTuple<int>(8)); ;
}
```

Now, I tried to achieve same output using `Create()` method, unfortunately, it is complaining about the return type:

```
private static ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<int>> OctupleUsingCreate()
{
    return ValueTuple.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ValueTuple.Create(8));
}
```

What is wrong here?
[image]

P.S. All packages are up-to-date and I am using Visual Studio 2017 -latest release.
[image]

*As suggested by Svick*

```
static ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<int>> OctupleUsingCreate()
{
  return ValueTuple.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
}
```

This prompts same compiler exception:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `ValueTuple.Create` already takes care of calling `ValueTuple.Create` on the 8th element. So while the correct type for 8-tuple is `ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<int>>`, you're creating `ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<ValueTuple<int>>>`. The fix is just to remove the second call to `ValueTuple.Create`:

```
static ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<int>> OctupleUsingCreate()
{
    return ValueTuple.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
}
```

Or you could just use the tuple syntax, but I'm assuming you have a reason to avoid it:

```
static (int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) OctupleUsingCreate()
{
    return (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that. But it was not working. I updated the question with snapshot and the code as sugegsted.

Comment: @GauravAroraa That's just a ReSharper bug. The code actually compiles and works fine.

Comment: @GauravAroraa I have just [reported it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464845).

Comment: Code is compiled - on another system, where Resharper is not installed.

Comment: @GauravAroraa Even if you have ReSharper installed, you can compile it. The red squiglies will still be there, but the build will succeed without errors.

Comment: its compiled but tests are failing. I know it looks weird but its happening. Thanks for raising ticket with Resharper team.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update this package: Microsoft.Net.Compilers to 2.0 (you need to show pre-release). It would fix the error, check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444981/c-sharp-7-valuetuple-compile-error)

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. All Nuget Packages are uptodate I have updated the question with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not a problem with the ValueTuple library or the C# compiler. No error on [TryRoslyn](https://sharplab.io/#f:%3Eil/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGPAbzxk5nwCcwA3GmhgohFGADUaJYKgAqwfCVQAeSMgA0MdVp3aIm/Yb16pM+YuVqDAPhswA8uWSXUAVXDRGPVENQAKAEoOLnZcLgiYHxceCElpWQUlVAA6b180fwBGLQAmLQBmLQAWLQBWLQA2LQB2LQAOQJxwrgBfPFagA=) with:

```
using System;
public class C 
{
    private static ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<int>> OctupleUsingCreate()
    {
        return ValueTuple.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    }
}
```