# Compilation fails when using System.ValueTuple

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, valuetuple

1. VS 2017 version 15.3.2
2. project targets framework 4.6.2
3. Installed nuget package System.ValueTuple  latest stable 4.4.0
4. Use value tuple, no error shown in editor
5. Run compile step, no errors in error window, only output window shows compilation failed and actual error messages

> Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

What is going on?

I created a branch in git from this one, and everything works fine. I merge changes back, compilation fails. I tried uninstalling package and re-installing, same thing.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? Have you updated it? If the answers are yes and then no, try disabling it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Disabling ReSharper has no effect.

Comment: Can you post some actual code?

Answer (score 0):

From [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41565541/430885):

You should update ***Microsoft.Net.Compilers*** package to (at least) version 2.0.