# Why doesn't range indexing work on dynamics

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I have some code, and it throws.  I don't understand why.

```
string s="asdf";
Console.WriteLine(s[1..3]);

dynamic d="asdf";
Console.WriteLine(d[1..3]); // throws 
// RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'string.this[int]' has some invalid arguments
```

Is there some statically resolved compiler magic?  The generated IL suggests this.

```
callvirt    System.String.Substring
```

Is there any way to use range indexing on dynamically declared expressions?

Comment: My guess is that `dynamic` is not `Countable` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#implicit-range-support .

Comment: "A type is ***Countable*** if it has a property named `Length` or `Count` with an accessible getter and a return type of `int`".  I don't see why it wouldn't qualify.

Answer (score 3):

Range Indexing is released in C# 8.0 and it doesn't support for dynamic, it cannot be translated to another code (in this case is `text.SubString()`) which means cannot resolve at runtime. I encountered the same problem with `dynamic` in [Lambda Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632521/tuple-lambda-syntax-suddenly-not-working-in-c-sharp) C# 8.0 also.

You might check [how this translation work](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboLIE8DCANgIYDOp6A3surZhlACw7ECWAdgBQCUVNdAqHAAM6CgF50AIjLAAZlIDc/AbSEBOTqQDacAHR7UAXW7KkquitXBc7YgFtWAY3TB0kmaXlKrguJqkASXZgAFMADxBpdDBXXRMzCzV/TikAJWJ2AHNQqKkYuP1DBKsAX2RSoA==) on the right side below code.

```
public class MyClass {
    public class RangeIndexer
    {
        public string MyString { get; set; }
        public char this[int index] { get => MyString[index]; }
        public string this[Range range] { get => MyString[range]; }
    }

    public void Main() {
        string s = "asdf";
        Console.WriteLine(s[1..3]); // Translate to text.SubString()

        dynamic d = "asdf";
        Console.WriteLine("Index: " + d[1]); // Address to this[int]
        //Console.WriteLine("Range1: " + d[1..3]); // Cannot translate to text.SubString() => Crashed
        Console.WriteLine("Range2: " + d.Substring(1, 2)); // Local method of string
        Console.WriteLine("Range3: " + $"{d}"[1..3]); // Cast as string and translate like Range1

        dynamic rangeIndexer = new RangeIndexer();
        rangeIndexer.MyString = "asdf";
        Console.WriteLine("Range4: " + rangeIndexer[1..3]); // Address to this[range]
    }
}
```

The `range indexing` is translated to `substring()` by IDE during compilation so it's not actually implemented in `string class`, therefore it's explained why only single indexing `d[1]` worked because it's declared.

[image]

So in short, we have 2 options

Option 1: In fact, `dynamic` is using Reflection technical to resolve and grab if it's in scope of the variable, method,.. that means no more translation codes will occur in Reflection. Thus, casting `dynamic` to specific type would help IDE translate them basically.

Option 2: Object should implement like `RangeIndexer` class to work as dynamic type which make sure the Reflection could grab it. But almost classic types don't support so it only works with your own model.

Answer (score 2):

## To extend an existing answer

> Is there some statically resolved compiler magic?

Yes, there is.

Indexer with range (`this[System.Range]` or `this[start..end]`) is supported in two ways: explicitly and implicitly.

***Explicitly***. If type declares indexer `this[System.Range]` then this indexer is used whenever we use notation `this[start..end]`. Compiler converts an expression `start..end` to the appropriate `System.Range` object and generates code that calls indexer `this[System.Range]`.

***Implicitly***. If type does not contain indexer `this[System.Range]` it could support range indexing implicitly. To be able to support range indexing implicitly type must satisfy next conditions:

- It must contain `Length` or `Count` property.
- It must contain `Slice(start, end)` method with two `int` parameters. Type `string` is a special case; for `string` type method `Substring` is used instead of `Slice`.

If type satisfies these conditions then when we use notation `this[start..end]` compiler generates code that calls method `Slice(start, end)` (or `Substring(start, end)` for `string`).

For more details see [C# specification: Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges).

---

So `string` type supports range indexing implicitly.

Consider the next code sample:

```
dynamic d = "asdf";
Console.WriteLine(d[1..3]);
```

It is impossible to determine during compilation that `dynamic` refers to the object that supports range indexing. Therefore complier does not generate code that calls method `Substring`. Instead it generates code that calls indexer `this[System.Range]`. `string` type does not contain such indexer, therefore `RuntimeBinderException` is generated.

Comment: I'm pleased to learn that there is at least a language specification proposal.  For some reason, I though MS stopped producing these around C# 5.

Comment: @recursive Currently there is a [draft C# 6 specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction) and [specification proposals for C# 7 and C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching).