# How to set default value using data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning ASP.Net MVC 5 and I want to set default value using data annotation for boolean property. Also I don't want to use the constructor to set the default value. Is it possible?

```
public class BalanceDetailMV
{
    public BalanceDetailMV()
    {
        this.isUnitNoEmptyInAllRow = true; // I do not want this
    }
    public bool isUnitNoEmptyInAllRow { get; set; }
}
```

My attmept:

```
[DefaultValue("true")]
 public bool isUnitNoEmptyInAllRow { get; set; }
```

But above does not work. Please guide me.

Comment: `DefaultValueAttribute` is not used by MVC. You need to set it in a constructor (or when you initialize your model)

Comment: Even if it were set like this, in C# "true" is a **string** and NOT a boolean.

Comment: @oerkelens: you are right. Actually I did put a bool true there. But it had compile time error and all. So, as a beginner I did some experimentation.

Answer (score 26):

If you're using C# 5 or earlier, you have to do it through the constructor, but since C# 6, you can do it like this:

```
public class BalanceDetailMV
{
    public bool isUnitNoEmptyInAllRow { get; set; } = true;
}
```

Comment: How can I know the version of cSharp. Can you kindly guide me.

Comment: Do, I need to check my web.config file or something?

Comment: @Unbreakable check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532977/880511

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532977/7002366 
In short, depends of what .NET Framework you're using.

Answer (score 15):

You might be having error if forgot to add `using System.ComponentModel;` at the top of your file where you use `DefaultValue` annotation.

For bool use

```
[DefaultValue(true)] 
public bool IsUnitNoEmptyInAllRow { get; set; }
```

Comment: It doesn't go to migration up method automatically though...