# Which C# version .NET Core uses?

Tags: c#, .net-core, version, c#-7.0, .net-core-2.0

I know that [C# version depends on .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532977/240564).

But .NET Core which version uses?

Particularly .NET Core 2? C#7?

Comment: I hope you have just been imprecise with your words. The C# version and. NET version are almost independent from each other: I could compile code written in C#7.2 with .NET3.5 and code in C#3 with .NET4.7.2. What you can do depends mostly on the Visual Studio version (And therefore: The compiler).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

.NET Core 2.0 [references](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/release/2.0.0/build/DependencyVersions.props) Roslyn 2.3, which corresponds to Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3 and supports C# 7.1.

Comment: does it mean if I use VS 2017 15.3 then C#7.1 used for all projects?

Comment: Each project has a LangVersion setting, which is "default" by default, which means "latest major version" (C# 7.0 in this case). If you want to use a minor version, such as C# 7.1, you'll have to change that setting. More information at http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Using-C-71-Features

Comment: The file you linked to says that the version of Roslyn used is 2.3.0-beta3-61816-04. I don't think that's right: the release version of .Net Core shouldn't be using beta version of Roslyn.

Comment: @svick This was apparently done intentionally for this release of Core. It's ok because Core redistributes/copies the compiler binaries. That said, a better design will be put in place soon. I'm not sure which issue tracks this, but I think it's related to this work: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16717

Comment: Can I check supported c# versions via dotnet cli ? Is there any roadmap for c# lang support in dotnet core ?

Comment: @tpx86 I don't think there is a convenient way to see what version of the C# compiler or what language versions it supports from dotnet cli.
The best I found on my box is something like: `dotnet exec "c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.0-preview1-007622\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll" -langversion:?`. 
That could be a worthwhile [cli](https://github.com/dotnet/cli) issue/request.

Comment: `dontnet --info` gives you the SDK version from which you can determine which versions of C# are supported.

Answer (score 13):

The C# [what's new version history page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history) gives a list of all versions plus their associated Visual Studio and .NET core version:

> - C# 7.3 Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7, and in the .NET Core 2.1 SDK 2.1.300 RC1
> - C# 7.2 Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5, and in the .NET Core 2.0 SDK.
> - C# 7.1 Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3, and in the .NET Core 2.0 SDK.
> - C# 7.0 Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Core 1.0 and later

C# 8.0 is still in preview at this time (3-Jul-2019).

You can also see your SDK version with this command:

```
dotnet --info
```

Sample output:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.300
 Commit:    adab45bf0c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.13
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.13-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.0
  Commit:  caa7b7e2ba

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft .net core [what's new page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/):

> NET Core 2.0 supports C# 7.1, which adds a number of new features, including:
>
> - The Main method, the application entry point, can be marked with the async keyword.
> - Inferred tuple names.
> - Default expressions.

You can also review check the [C# Language versioning page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

> The compiler determines a default based on these rules:
>
> .NET Core 2.x C# 7.3