# Visual Studio 2017 Mac C# Version

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I get the version of C# that is running on my Mac?  I have checked the website for Visual Studio 2017 and have not been able to find the version.

I Have added About section:
=== Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===

Version 7.3 (build 799)
Installation UUID: 4be5485a-d8da-48ba-bd34-603b90ee6a5f
Runtime:
    Mono 5.4.1.7 (2017-06/e66d9abbb27) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

```
Package version: 504010007
```

=== NuGet ===

Version: 4.3.1.4445

=== .NET Core ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Version: 2.0.0
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Sdks
SDK Version: 2.0.0
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.0
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 9.2 (13772)
Build 9C40b

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 4.0.0.214 (Visual Studio Community)

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 8.1.0.24 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/alexwebster/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        7.1 (API level 25)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5
SDK Platform Tools Version: 26.0.2
SDK Build Tools Version: 25.0.3

Java SDK: /usr
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 11.6.1.2 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 6857dfcc
Branch: xcode9.2
Build date: 2017-12-04 21:20:41-0500

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.3.2
Hash: 461f09a
Branch: 1.3-release
Build date: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 18:26:57 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 703000799
Git revision: df590420ea5bc681994baefff2eabdaad889fba9
Build date: 2017-12-05 09:23:45-05
Xamarin addins: 51068d6eaf3b6fb4fbc72b33cb869b0ebff04ec5
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-5

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.13.2
Darwin 17.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0
    Thu Nov  9 18:09:22 PST 2017
    root:xnu-4570.31.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: You mean you've installed it, but you're not sure what version you've installed?  Have you tried "About Visual Studio" from the first menu?

Comment: No I know what version of Visual Studio I have installed.  But what version of C# I have running.  Like do I have the latest release of C# 7 or do I have C# 7 even on my laptop

Comment: You're on .net core 2.0 which is C# 7.1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901362/which-c-sharp-version-net-core-uses