# Automatic properties compiler error

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

Writing a simple class in c# comes up with error "Not all code path return a value"

```
public class Genre
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line? (compiles fine for me) This error is usually generated when a non-void function misses a return statement

Comment: Compiles without error for me in LINQPad, with a `new Genre().Name = "hi";` thrown in for good measure. What's the actual failing code?

Comment: I'm sure this class doesn't create a error

Comment: In a side note, you can use the snippet propfull so you can write code faster and without errors - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx

Comment: Which .net framework you are working on?

Comment: 4.6.2 framework

Comment: This is a new-ish syntax, so check which version of the C# compiler you're using.  You'll need C# 6.0 or above, I think. Note that this is not the same as the .NET framework version. See https://davefancher.com/2014/08/25/c-6-0-expression-bodied-members/ and other online resources

Comment: where do i check the compiler version?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647107/5947043 (and many others again, if you take the time to google something like "check c# compiler version"). Google is your friend...

Comment: @ADyson I think it's C# 7, which means you must have VS 2017 or above. AnKing, what's your VS version? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#more-expression-bodied-members

Comment: @AnKing: Open project in  visual studio right click on project -> properties->build-> advance and check the language version dropdown... see what c# versions it show

Comment: I use VS2015, changed compiler version to 6, but still doesnt work. do I really need VS2017 for this syntax to work?

Comment: @AnKing As I said, you must have VS2017, otherwise you'll have to use the old way

Comment: @Magnetron Good spot. It's C#6 for property "get" using this syntax, and C# 7 to use property "set"  this way. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members for that. But also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015 - you can install different compilers into a particular project when using Nuget on VS 2015 and possibly earlier, although it's not clear if this is really supported or not. Of course a command-line compiler could always be used, instead.

Comment: @ADyson good to know. But as the post says, it'll work but will show sintax error.

Comment: Might seem ridicolous, but make sure that you are compiling the right project.

Comment: I think I'll just have to upgrade the visual studio at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is a [new addition to C#7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#more-expression-bodied-members), so the options are:

- Use Visual Studio 2017 or above, or VS Code (if dotnet core project)
- Install the new compiler from Nuget, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015) on how to do so
- Use the old way:

  ```
  public class Genre
  {
      private string _name;

      public string Name
      {
          get { return _name; }
          set { _name = value; }
      }
  }
  ```