# How to detect C# (not CLR) version programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net

I use C# for .NET. I know how to programmatically detect CLR version of a .NET assembly, but can’t find out how to programmatically detect the C# version in my code. Anyone has idea? TIA.

Comment: This is not possible. The language version does only matter for the compiler at compile time. At runtime, there is no language version.

Comment: Why are you asking this? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have a problem X and think Y is the solution. When that fails you ask about Y, not X. There's no language at runtime, only the IL. Do you *really* want to know the language version of the source code that produced your  executable even though you can't do anything with it?

Comment: Dupicate of [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532942/which-version-of-c-sharp-am-i-using)

Comment: @hub that answer hasn't worked for the last 7 years - all C# versions up to 7.3 can target any of the 4.x frameworks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: nonetheless, it's as close as the OP's going to get. And in fact, the answer to have the csc.exe compiler print the version is in fact a workable approach. The OP could execute that as a custom build step, parsing the result and embedding that result in their program somehow. Just because C# itself doesn't provide a direct way, doesn't mean it's not possible.

Comment: You don't have to target the version of .NET your C# compiler version was released with. You don't even have to target .NET Framework. You could target Mono, Xamarin, .NET Core.

Answer (score 7):

The C# source code has been translated to IL when the assembly is generated. It's no longer relevant what C# version was used to generate the IL (or indeed, if C# was used), nor is that information stored.

There are some IL features that will not be used by older versions of C# (e.g. support for nullable reference types and async streams). If the IL contains such constructs, you can rule out older C# versions. It's highly non-trivial to make that determination.

Here's a breakdown of the assembly format (click through to the second article in the series). You'll see there's no information describing the language or version that generated the assembly.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/

Comment: And mind that IL could also come from other languages than C# as well.

Comment: Good point! Updated the answer.