# How to get c# version on rutime

Tags: c#, .net-core

How I can get c# version from my code on run time? I use .net core. For example I can get framework version with this code:

```
FrameworkName = Assembly
    .GetEntryAssembly()?
    .GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>()?
    .FrameworkName
```

And I need something similar for C# version.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532942/which-version-of-c-sharp-am-i-using

Comment: The OP is asking about C# spec that was used.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need the C# version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing. The language version is completely lost in the compilation process, as the end result is just compiled IL code.

The fact that you used C# 6 or C# 7 or Visual Basic.NET is not retained in any form in the runtime program, and is only used to emit code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In this case, exist any way to get c# version on CLI? Something like `dotnet --language_version`?

Comment: @stepozer That only lives on the project file, that's used to launch the compiler with the right language version. Once compiled, CLI or code or anything, C# doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: So, that i asked, where to get it?

Comment: @stepozer You can look at the `LangVersion` tag of the csproj file, that's the only place where the language version is held. Of course, that file lives only on the development working copy and isn't deployed at all, so at runtime it won't be available, unless you take actions to ship it.