# Using System.CommandLine with custom Main() signature

Tags: c#, command-line, system.commandline

I'm trying to use `System.CommandLine` and I've installed the nuget package:

```
Install-Package System.CommandLine -Version 2.0.0-beta1.21308.1
```

According to [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/net-parse-the-command-line-with-system-commandline#keep-simple-things-simple), I should be able to just write a Main() method with my signature and it should auto-magically work:

```
static void Main(FileInfo input, FileInfo output)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello World! {input} {output}");
}
```

However my Main() method signature is rejected and I get `CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`.

Am I doing something wrong? According to the article, this is how `System.CommandLine` should be working.

Comment: What version of the C# language are you using? The feature you're trying to use is called ["Top level statements"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements) and was introduced with c# 9.

Comment: I am using .NET 5.0 and according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532942/which-version-of-c-sharp-am-i-using/19533393, that determines the C# version which should be 9.0

Comment: Did you follow [the instructions for using `DragonFruit`](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/main/docs/DragonFruit-overview.md)?

Comment: Thank you, I needed to run `Install-Package System.CommandLine.DragonFruit -Version 0.3.0-alpha.21216.1` and now it works. Could you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to target .NET 5.0, and run these 2 commands in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package System.CommandLine -Version 2.0.0-beta1.21308.1
Install-Package System.CommandLine.DragonFruit -Version 0.3.0-alpha.21216.1
```

After that it should work.

---

Explanation: In order to use [`System.CommandLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/net-parse-the-command-line-with-system-commandline#keep-simple-things-simple), you also need to install a NuGet package called [`DragonFruit`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CommandLine.DragonFruit).

It's this package that enables the custom command line parameters.

See here for details: https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/main/docs/DragonFruit-overview.md

Also note that you also need C# version 9 or later to support [`Top-Level Statements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements), but you have confirmed that you're using that - I mention it here for other readers.