# Determine C# version in Visual Studio 2019 / .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I have a project running **.NET Framework 4.8** and in the project's properties under "Build > Advanced > Language Version" Visual Studio states "Automatically selected based on framework version". Wouldn't it be great, if they were to show me which version was automatically selected? :o/

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version (amongst others) my project should be using **C# 7.3**, but I cannot use the latest features. "Latest" as in "as far as Microsoft will let me go with the old .net Framework".

How can I determine which C# version is being used and how can I update to the "latest" version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which version of C# am I using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532942/which-version-of-c-sharp-am-i-using)

Comment: This answer is most direct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64508800/3195477

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if it is possible to view the currently selected lang version from within visual studio. But it is fairly easy to specify the latest version.

From the same article you linked, edit your csproj file in a text editor and add the line `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`, For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You should also be able to specify `preview` as the langversion to get the preview version.

Note that not all language versions are supported for all .net platforms, so using this on .Net framework might not technically be supported. But I have been running the latest version on .net 4.8 and not noticed any major issues so far. The most noticeable issue is having to manually edit all the csproj files.